# Empty area under Number pad in iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uikeyboard

I am not sure why this is happening. An empty area is coming inside the keyboard under all the keys. The keyboard type is Number Pad.

[image: keyboard with empty area]

Comment: Did u tried disabling Shortcut and predictive text and input assistant from keyboard in IPad Settings?

Comment: How can i disable it thru programming?

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480463/how-to-remove-the-grey-bottom-bar-in-ipad-simulator/34356959#34356959